# How to make fragments listen to MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, callback, fragment

I am trying to implement a callback in which a button press in the layout of the MainActivity would propagate a Boolean value to two fragments visible on the screen. I would like those two fragments to change the color of their background when they receive that message.

How would this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class DemoActivity extends Activity{
private boolean someBoolean;
private Fragment frag1,frag2; // init them and begin transaction

   btnclick.setonClickListener{
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v){
       frag1.changeColor(someBooean);
       frag2.changeColor(someBoolean);
   }
}

class Frag1 extends Fragment{

  public void changeColor(boolean someVal){
     getRootView().setBackgroundColor(someVal ? R.color.colo_one:R.color.color_two);
  }
}


class Frag2 extends Fragment{

  public void changeColor(boolean someVal){
     getRootView().setBackgroundColor(someVal ? R.color.colo_one:R.color.color_two);
  }
}
```